# Tap to Save Photo Android

Tags: java, android

I am pretty new to Android development and I'm trying to figure out how to tap an image in my app and save it to the device. When the image is tapped I want a Save button to appear and when that is pressed, a toast should appear saying the picture was saved. On iOS I am able to do this with UIActionSheet.

I should also mention that the image view image is downloaded from a URL using Picasso.

I just tried this and it says the image saved but when I go to the photos app on my phone, the image is not there.

```
largeImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                saveButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                largeImage.getDrawable();
                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)largeImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

                OutputStream outStream = null;
                File file = new File(storageDirectory, "er.PNG");
                try {
                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
                    outStream.flush();
                    outStream.close();

                    Toast.makeText(FlickrImageActivity.this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(FlickrImageActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(FlickrImageActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                saveButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");    
myDir.mkdirs();
Random generator = new Random();
int n = 10000;
n = generator.nextInt(n);
String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
File file = new File (myDir, fname);
if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
try {
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
       finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
       out.flush();
       out.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
}

Manifest permission

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use RelativeLayout to contain a ImageView and a Button.

Align both of them center in parent

inside the activity, set the button visibility to "gone"

call setOnClickListener of the ImageView and Button to your Activity

implement OnClickListener in your Activity

inside onClick(View v), if the view clicked is the ImageView, set the visibility of Button to "visible"

inside onClick(View v), if the view clicked is the Button, save the image to disk

** how to save image to disk

if the image source is drawable resources, use BitmapFactory.decodeResource to create a Bitmap then use Bitmap.compress to export to a specific path

- specific path is recommended to be obtained from Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory

then notify the Android to refresh gallery

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context,
new String[] { imagePath }, null,
new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {                      
    @Override
    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
        //....                              
    }
});
```

Then use a Toast.makeText(context, "message here").show(); to show the message to user

Answer (score 0):

See below steps to acheive this in Android :

```
 1. Create layout with ImageView & 'Save' named Button

 2.By deafult set 'Save' Button's visibility = gone/invisible

3. Apply click listener on both the views (ImageView & Button)

4. OnClick of ImageView, set 'Save' Button's visibility = visible

5. onclick of save button click call your save image to sdcard logic. Check below link for that.
http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/07/save-file-to-sd-card.html
```

Hope this will help you.